# The appropriate way to securely use flash in webpage

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, authentication, database-connection

I will start with an intro to prevent you making specific questions.

**Introduction**

I have no idea about flash programing. What i do know, is that when i browse a page that contains a flash object, i can somehow save it in my computer. I just want to know (before i start learning flash coding) if I will be able to do what i want to.

**The problem:**

I want to create some web flash content(let's say a game or a presentation), which will be visible only to users who have logged in in my webpage. My idea is to use for example php and mysql to create the login page, save user in SESSION and embed the flash objects in my pages. Pages won't be visible when user is not logged in.

**The questions**

- Is something like this secure? ie, can someone download the presentation and have access to it offline or send it to his friend?
- Can a flash object connect somehow to database and retrieve data? ie, saving the presentation in mysql
- Do you have any other suggestions except from the above (php+mysql+flash)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is something like this secure? ie, can someone download the
>   presentation and have access to it offline or send it to his friend?

It should be ok, since if user cannot navigate to the page where the .swf is embedded he obviously won`t be able to download it. And even if someone downloads the .swf and runs it  locally, you could check session ID, generated by your backend which should be passed to the .swf by its wrapper page when the user logs in and runs you app in the browser.

> Can a flash object connect somehow to database and retrieve data? ie,
>   saving the presentation in mysql

Not directly and it won`t be a good idea for security reasons. The common practice is to write some services on the backed and use them to transfer data between database and the client.

> Do you have any other suggestions except from the above
>   (php+mysql+flash)?

If you feel comfortable with PHP and MySQL then there is no reason to switch to something else. And for PHP, I`d recommend using AMFPHP to write your services as it is allows you to make use of binary AMF format for serializing your data and therefore decrease service call duration.

Comment: Thank you. about the 1st question i think that from "page info"->media->download i can download the .swf and run it locally. could i check within the flash code if there is a user logged in?

Comment: Generate session id when user logs in and pass it to your app (.swf) from the wrapper page. When making service calls from your app, just pass along session id and let backend code check if it is valid (created when someone logged in and not expired yet). If it is invalid - don`t return any data. By doing this you ensure that anyone who can`t log in into your system won`t be able to use the .swf even if they have it downloaded.